# How to attach all tap dev by cilium/ebpf ? What's the best way except attach tap dev one by one if it is not support?

Tags: go, ebpf

How to attach all tap dev by cilium/ebpf ? What's the best way except attach tap dev one by one if it is not support ?

I read document not found mutil attach function.

Comment: Try adding more context to the question, code samples, explain what you have tried and why do you think it did not work...

Answer (score 1):

As of the writing of this answer, there is no way to attach XDP/TC programs to multiple network devices within a single "call".

I believe the only program type where something like this is possible is with [kprobes](https://lwn.net/Articles/885811/).

So you will have to list all devices and attach one by one.